# location manager giving null coordinates

Tags: ios, xcode, core-location

The following code results in null coordinates. The weird thing is the UIAlert prompting the app to use current location appears briefly before the user can select yes.

My code which i have used :

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;
NSLog(@"%.8f",latitude);
NSLog(@"%.8f",longitude);
```

The NSLog prints `0.0000000` for both coordinates.

Thanks!

Comment: I made UILabels and set the texts respectively to the coordinates but still have the same error of the temporary UIalert and the coordinates are still 0.000000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you're getting 0 is because the location manager hasn't collected any data at that point (it has started thought)

You need to set your class as the delegate of the location manager (ie supplying a function that is called whenever a new location is retrieved), and also retain your location manager.

```
// Inside .m file

@interface MyClass () <CLLocationManagerDelegate> // Declare this class to implement protocol CLLocationManagerDelegate

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager* locationManager; // Retains it with strong keyword

@end

@implementation MyClass

// Inside some method

   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   self.locationManager.delegate = self;
   self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
   self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
   [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

// Delegate method
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    CLLocation* loc = [locations lastObject]; // locations is guaranteed to have at least one object
    float latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude;
    float longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude;
    NSLog(@"%.8f",latitude);
    NSLog(@"%.8f",longitude);
}
```

Comment: It works, however I get three pairs of the coordinates instead of one. I implement all the self."" parameters in viewDidLoad. Not sure if that makes any difference. Any ideas? Also, when I reload the screen it prints out one pair as desired.

Comment: The arrays were meant to contain the locations that your application somehow "missed" (not sure what this means, maybe when the app was busy or in the background). Often the last one is sufficient, but it all depends on what sort of application you're making. If, say, you're trying to record where the user *had* been (movement history), you may want to read the whole array.

Comment: I did some debugging and it seems to be the the locationManager function gets called multiple times. Any way around this?

Comment: It's not a bug, the location manager calls whenever it acquires a new user location (even when user hasn't moved). If you want to get the location only once, turn it off using `[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]` after you have got the location. Other options are to check the coordinates to see if user has actually moved, or set `distanceFilter` to a non-zero value (it's in meters btw).